# How to config app.config to take test data from an excel file using Nunit?

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, nunit

I'm trying to create a data driven test using selenium, C# and Nunit. I'm using the app.config to find my excel sheet so that it can run the test

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="mydatafile" value="DataSource=C:\Users\christophermclellan\theExample.xlsx"/>
</appSettings>
```

I've set my configuration up as follows

```
setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mydatafile"];
```

and reading in my values as follows

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(setting, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

When I run this in I'm getting the following error

> *DataDrivenTestFramework.Driver.GoogleSearch: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Sorry, we couldn't find
>   Data Source=C:\Users\christophermclellan\theExample.xlsx. Is it
>   possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?*

If anyone could point me in the right direction of where to go from here that you be great

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the DataSource part of the string, just the path to the file.  You would also need to escape your path, eg:

```
<add key="mydatafile" value="C:\\Users\\christophermclellan\\theExample.xlsx"/>
```